# ¿De qué forma podría mantener información sobre cambios en el código de mi aplicación Android para generar un registro de cambios?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estuve viendo que Android tiene una [API para anotaciones](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/annotation) y quería saber de qué forma podría usarla para hacer anotaciones sobre actualizaciones en mi código, de forma que pueda generar fácilmente una especie de registro de cambios (change log) sin tener que preocuparme de ir anotando los cambios en otra parte.

Pongo un ejemplo:

Hoy he descubierto un error en mi código, en esta parte:

```
public void launchVolley() {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            /*
              Aquí hubo un cambio
            */
            Request.Method.GET, URL_NONA + strFechaHoy, null,
            response -> {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
```

La constante que había en lugar de `URL_NONA` era errónea y lo he corregido. Pero voy a esperar unos días para lanzar la actualización, porque estoy modificando una parte más compleja de la App y me llevará unos días terminar de probarla.

Mi pregunta es ¿de qué manera podría anotar esta parte:

```
            /*
              Aquí hubo un cambio
            */
```

Para que me genere de algún modo un reporte de todos esos pequeños cambios que pude haber hecho?

Comment: Y no sería más fácil usar un sistema de control de versiones como git para eso?? Puedes inicializar un repositorio de git en local sin necesidad de subirlo a ningún lado, simplemente para llevar un histórico de los cambios (y poder volver a las otras versiones/cambiar de rama a voluntad)

Comment: @Benito-B yo tengo el código sincronizado en un repositorio de GitHub de hecho, lo hice desde un principio sobre todo por seguridad, para tener una copia del proyecto en caso de cualquier problema en mi dispositivo. Pero no soy un experto en control de versiones y esas cosas. Solamente configuré Android Studio con mi cuenta de GitHub y mando los cambios cada cierto tiempo allí, nada más.

Comment: Pues si ya tienes git configurado, asegúrate de que cuando haces `commit` añades un mensaje *descriptivo*, luego es posible ver los diferentes mensajes de cada commit en forma de log (no recuerdo cómo, pero lo he visto varias veces!). Eso si, para que esto funcione bien es necesario hacer commits bastante... específicos. Yo acostumbraba a hacer un commit al día, ahora hago un commit por cada *cambio* (Aunque el cambio incluya varios archivos van todos juntos, pero siempre que pueda describir dicho cambio en una frase corta)

Comment: Elimino mi anterior comentario pues he encontrado el recurso original que usé para buscar esos comandos, y está todo bien explicado. Es un [capítulo de la documentación de git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) e incluso explica cómo filtrar por fechas el log! Creo que eso hará exactamente lo que necesitas, sin necesidad de usar ninguna librería más :). El comando concreto del que hablaba yo es: `git log --pretty=format:"%s"`